# How to fix '' 'Mul' object has no attribute 'sp' " error in Python (using Sympy & Math)

Tags: python, sympy

I'm making a program that uses derivates to calculate an error.

I keep getting this error : 'Mul' object has no attribute 'sp'.

The solutions to this error that i've found so far are when people import everything from sympy and math (from sympy/math import *) because both sympy and math have a sin() function.

But as you can see from my code bellow i don't have it like that and the error still shows up, why?

```
import sympy as sp
from math import factorial

def F(x):
  return 4*(x**2)+sp.sin(9*x)

sp.init_printing()
x=sp.symbols('x')
def D1(x1):
  return(sp.diff(F(x),x,1).sp.subs(x,x1))

def D2(x1):
  return(sp.diff(F(x),x,2).sp.subs(x,x1))

def D3(x1):
  return(sp.diff(F(x),x,3).sp.subs(x,x1))

def maxD3(x1,x2):
  if(D3(x1)>D3(x2)):
    return D3(x1)
  else:
    return D3(x2)

erro1 = (1/factorial(3))*maxD3(-1,1)*abs((0.3-(-1))*(0.3-1))
erro1 = (1/factorial(3))*maxD3(-1,1)*abs((0.83-(-1))*(0.83-1))

print("Erro f(0.3): ", erro1)
print("Erro f(0.83): ", erro2)
```

Also have changed "from math import factorial" to "import math as math" and the error also keeps showing up.

I'm using Python 3.6.1.

EDIT: Full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    erro1 = (1/math.factorial(3))*maxD3(-1,1)*abs((0.3-(-1))*(0.3-1))
  File "main.py", line 19, in maxD3
    if(D3(x1)>D3(x2)):
  File "main.py", line 16, in D3
    return(sp.diff(F(x),x,3).sp.subs(x,x1))
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'sp'
```

Comment: `import math as math` doesn't do anything. You're aliasing the module with its own name

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: `sp.diff(F(x),x,1).sp.subs(x,x1)` i dont have the means to test, but this does not look good. Why reference the module again? It looks like you're trying to chain the operations that should be done in steps

Comment: @roganjosh i've done this before importing everything (*) from sympy so i had to write like `diff(F(x),x,1).subs(x,x1)` and it worked, i just added the sp now because i had to import diferently. I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Of course it's different. You're chaining operators and referencing the module. You can't do that.

Comment: `subs` is a method of a `sympy` object.  It is not a `sympy` function.  Thus `sp.subs` (or `subs` in the import * case) will give an error.  `sp.diff().subs(...)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the corrected version of your code

```
import sympy as sp
from math import factorial

def F(x):
  return 4*(x**2)+sp.sin(9*x)

sp.init_printing()
x=sp.symbols('x')
def D1(x1):
  return(sp.diff(F(x),x,1).subs(x,x1)) # subs instead of sp.subs

def D2(x1):
  return(sp.diff(F(x),x,2).subs(x,x1)) # subs instead of sp.subs

def D3(x1):
  return(sp.diff(F(x),x,3).sp.subs(x,x1))

def maxD3(x1,x2):
  if(D3(x1)>D3(x2)):
    return D3(x1)
  else:
    return D3(x2)

erro1 = (1/factorial(3))*maxD3(-1,1)*abs((0.3-(-1))*(0.3-1))
erro2 = (1/factorial(3))*maxD3(-1,1)*abs((0.83-(-1))*(0.83-1)) # erro2 instead of erro1

print("Erro f(0.3): ", erro1)
print("Erro f(0.83): ", erro2)
```

Output on my system:

```
('Erro f(0.83): ', 0)

('Erro f(0.83): ', 0)
```

Is this the expected output?

Also, you don't need to import everything from sympy. You can just import what you need.
Example:

```
>>> from sympy import sin, symbols, diff
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> f = x**3 + sin(x)
>>> print(diff(f, x))
3*x**2 + cos(x)
>>> print(diff(f, x).subs(x, 1))
cos(1) + 3
```